# Source maps reference non existent source file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, kendo-ui

While compiling my project with webpack, the webpack compiler throws the following error for every Kendo UI component I have installed and using.

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-dropdowns-react-wrapper/dist/es/autocomplete/index.js
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) Cannot find source file '../../../src/autocomplete/index.tsx': Error: Can't resolve '../../../src/autocomplete/index.tsx' in 'C:\Users\apearson\Documents\ILS\OmniView\OmniView.UI\node_modules\@progress\kendo-dropdowns-react-wrapper\dist\es\autocomplete'
@ ./node_modules/@progress/kendo-dropdowns-react-wrapper/dist/es/index.js 1:0-43
@ ./ClientApp/components/elements/SearchDrawer.tsx
@ ./ClientApp/components/pages/Checks.tsx
@ ./ClientApp/App.tsx
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./ClientApp/App.tsx
```

This error is caused by the Kendo UI module's source map referencing a relative path that does not exist.  Here is a snippet of the source map that is causing the problem and the current file structure after an npm install.

```
{"version":3,"file":"index.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["../../../src/autocomplete/index.tsx"],"names":[],"mappings":";;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;AAAA,OAAO,
```

[image: Kendo UI Module File Structure]

As you can see the `"sources": "../../../src/autocomplete/index.tsx"` is the problem causing code.

Is this a known issue?

Current setup:
- Kendo UI: 2017.3.1116
- Webpack: 3.6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current workaround that I have is to do a search and replace on the source map reference for each Kendo UI module in the actual code.  This eliminates the warning from happening during the webpack compile.

This is not a good solution since it removes the source maps from ever being used.

Update 1: The problem was caused by running the [Source Map Loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/source-map-loader) alongside the typescript loader.